# How to make a remote server appear in my subnet when remote debugging in visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I have an application running on a remote server I want to debug locally. I read the MSDN blogs, but I am not able to get the remote server on the remote .
connections.

Debug>Attach to Process> Transport (Remote)> Find
Says "Found 0 connections on my subnet"

I have added remote debugging monitor to be available publicly in the firewall settings at both my local machine and on the remote server.
Could anyone please help me with this?

My IP is for example 192.22.20.XXX and the remote server is on 192.22.21.YYY.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how "remote" is "remote"? same subnet? different subnet?

Comment: I am not sure of that one, will comment tomorrow. They are all on the same internal network though..

Comment: I checked, they are not on the same subnet. Is it possible to still debug? @MarcB

Comment: no idea, but if they're in different subnets then whatever autodetection VS is doing won't work.